# Gitlab CI - How to get all available environments

Tags: gitlab, environment-variables, gitlab-ci

I am currently trying to deploy to multiple countries with Gitlab.

My current .gitlab-ci.yml

```html
action-deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - ls $PROJECT_URL
  environment:
    name: DE/$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    url: https://$PROJECT_URL
```

General problem:

Here the DE (Germany) is a single country. How Do I gather all available XXXXXXX/$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH environments from the gitlab project settings and deploy to all of them?

Main question:

Is there a way in Gitlab CI to get all available environments?

Comment: Do you have one repository and one project per location? Do you want to get the values of env variables from the deployment jobs of the other locations? You can always do API calls whenever you have a shell: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/project_level_variables.html

Comment: no. one repository and multiple locations. We have a single gitlab project and need to deploy it to multiple countries (example: Germany, Spain, Italy). And for each country we have different configuration of the project.  Thank you. This API call will help. Will run it and get all possible environments